# Trapezium/trapezoid — why are the US/UK definitions swapped around?

Tags: meaning, etymology, american-english, british-english, mathematics

These are the US definitions...

[Trapezoid](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/trapezoid.html) *— a 4-sided flat shape with straight sides that has a pair of opposite sides parallel.*

[Trapezium](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/trapezium.html) *— a 4-sided flat shape with straight sides and NO parallel sides.*

[The meanings of the two words are exactly reversed between the US and British interpretations.](http://www.mathopenref.com/trapezium.html)

I don't know how relevant this is, but in general the [-oid](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-oid) suffix *(humanoid, android, asteroid)* means *"similar to (but not **actually**)"*, whereas [-ium](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ium) *(consortium, auditorium, emporium)* is a "noun-forming" suffix, [sometimes having the sense of bigger or more complicated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-ium).

The British definitions therefore seem more "logical" to me - our *trapezoid* is superficially "like" a *trapezium* (it has four sides), but it's not actually the same (no sides are parallel). It's also tempting to think Brits were using the words first.

Is there any explanation for how this US/UK difference came about?

Comment: ...and of course then there's the [*trapezius*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezius_muscle).

Comment: It's not just Britain, but the rest of the world. I have never seen *trapezium* used for a shape with no parallel sides (and I'd like to keep it that way, hehe).

Comment: If British English [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trapezoidal%20rule,trapezoid%20rule,trapezium%20rule&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6) for *trapezoidal rule,trapezoid rule,trapezium rule* (alternate terms for exactly the same thing; the rule is the same regardless of its name) is to be believed, people in Britain far more frequently say *trapezoidal rule* when by rights they should be saying *[trapezium rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezium_rule)*.

Comment: And here I thought a trapezium was a gym for circus performers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [trapezium article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trapezium.html) at MathWorld provides the following explanation (referencing OED) of how the U.S.- and U.K.-differing definitions arose:

> According to the Oxford English Dictionary, the confusion of trapezium and trapezoid between the United States and Great Britain dates back to an error in Hutton's Mathematical Dictionary in 1795, the first work of its kind in the United States, which directly reversed the accepted meanings. Hutton assigned trapezium to "no sides parallel" and trapezoid to "two sides parallel" (Simpson and Weiner 1992, p. 2101).
>
> After 1795 in the United States, the Hutton definitions became standard, while in the British empire, the Proclus definitions remained standard. Two hundred years later, the controversy remains. Country by country, region by region, and even teacher by teacher, the definitions of trapezoid and trapezium are commonly swapped.

Note, "the Proclus definitions" were mentioned earlier in the MathWorld article:

> Proclus (also Heron and Posidonius) divided quadrilaterals into parallelograms and non-parallelograms. For the latter, Proclus assigned trapezium to "two sides parallel," and trapezoid to "no sides parallel." Archimedes also defined a trapezium as having precisely two parallel sides (Heath 1956, pp. 188-190).

*Edit:*  Regarding distinctions made by Euclid, Proclus, Archimedes and others, 
on pages [189 and 190](http://books.google.com/books?id=RzwNuNRePZUC&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=%22on+divisions+of+figures+Archimedes%22&source=bl&ots=8T9aNAswPx&sig=pYTWUJTA1wMvUX5m6n4sjyw8a-k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=q86UT-jLKaaLiAL9gcEp&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22on%20divisions%20of%20figures%20Archimedes%22&f=false) of volume I of Thomas L. Heath's *The Thirteen Books of Euclid's Elements* (1956) we find:

> As Euclid has not yet defined parallel lines and does not anywhere define a *parallelogram*, he is not in a position to make the more elaborate classification of quadrilaterals attributed by Proclus to Posidonius and appearing also in Heron's Definitions.  It may be shown by the following diagram, distinguishing seven species of quadrilaterals.

The diagram from Heath (representing quadrilateral classification per Posidonius, Proclus, and Heron) is shown below.  One may compare this diagram with that shown in wikipedia's [quadrilateral taxonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Taxonomy) section.  That taxonomy does not have the word *trapezoid* in it, because it says "*trapezium* here is ... British" and "inclusive definitions are used throughout".  (A British trapezoid is a convex quadrilateral that is not a British trapezium. The only categories of the taxonomy that can contain a convex British trapezoid are the quadrilateral, simple, convex, tangential, cyclic, kite, and bicentric categories.)

[image: P-P-H Chart]

Heath then continues:

> It will be observed that, while Euclid in the above definition classes as *trapezia* all quadrilaterals other than squares, oblongs, rhombi, and rhomboids, the word is in this classification restricted to quadrilaterals having two sides (only) parallel, and *trapezoid* is used to denote the rest.  Euclid appears to have used *trapezium* in the restricted sense of a quadrilateral with two sides parallel in his book περι διαιρεσεων (on divisions of figures).  Archimedes uses it in the same sense, but in one place describes it more precisely as a *trapezium* with its two sides parallel.

I think the first *it* in  the last sentence refers to *trapezium* but don't understand what the second *it* refers to.  Consequently, it is unclear to me whether MathWorld's assertions re Archimedes' definitions are correct.

*Edit:* In a 
[trapezium and trapezoid](http://linguistlist.org/ask-ling/message-details1.cfm?asklingid=200359948)  article on *The Linguist List*, we read the following quote from Oxford English Dictionary (under sense (c) of *trapezium*):

> An irregular quadrilateral having neither pair of opposite sides parallel. (The usual sense in England from c1800 to c1875. Now rare. This sense is the one that is standard in the U.S., but in practice quadrilateral is used rather than trapezium.)

This indicates that during the 80 years after [Hutton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Hutton) (a much-published English mathematician, born 1737 at Newcastle-on-Tyne, 1778 [Copley Medal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copley_Medal) recipient) gave the definitions now in use in the U.S., those same definitions were also in use in England, afterwards falling into disuse (*ie* being reversed or set aright) in  England.  The OED goes on to imply that in the  U.S., the all-encompassing term *quadrilateral* rather than (U.S.) *trapezium* is used to refer to quadrilaterals that do not fall into more-specific categories such as squares, rectangles, parallelograms, (British) trapezia, etc.

Comment: On the other hand, [Euclid](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/defI22.html) seems to have used *trapezium* for any quadrilateral more general than a parallelogram, while Proclus introduced the distinction between *trapezium* and *trapezoid* (understandable, if Archimedes and Euclid had different definitions for *trapezium*).

Comment: So are we saying that American is Euclidean, and British is Archimedean?

Comment: @Andrew, yes and no; Euclid did not distinguish a two-parallel-sides figure, *ie* called *trapezia* all the figures now called trapeziums and trapezoids in the U.S. or trapezoids and trapeziums in the U.K.

Comment: I'd always assumed *quadrilateral* meant *any four-sided figure*, and *trapezium* was any quadrilateral with *no parallel sides and no equal angles*. So a rectangle or rhombus, for example, is a quadrilateral, but it's not a trapezium. But on [this page](http://linguistlist.org/ask-ling/message-details1.cfm?asklingid=200359948), *"in practice quadrilateral is used rather than trapezium"* seems to imply the two words are equivalent. Are they?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, no; see 2nd edit (at end of answer).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: in practice, people would probably say "irregular quadrilateral" rather than "trapezium/trapezoid" for a quadrilateral with no parallel sides.

Comment: Astonishing! Regardless of whether Hutton would have acknowledged his "mistake" as a genuine oversight, or if he truly thought his definitions were "correct", it seems clear they were at odds with mainstream established usage at the time of publication. It almost beggars belief that no-one pointed out the error early (or Hutton/his publishers chose to ignore anyone who did), and that it's survived to become the accepted US standard to this day. I can see that once it was being taught in schools, retraction would be difficult - but I'm amazed it ever got that far in the first place!